# Laravel hasMany updating relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So In laravel I have a hasMany relation, Lets call it fruits. 
A user can only have 1 of each fruit and its a checkbox on the profile page. At the moment
I have this code

```
if (!empty($data['fruits'])) {
  $fruits = $data['fruits'];
  foreach($user->fruits as $i) {
    $i->delete();
  }
  for($a=0;$a<count($fruits);$a++)
    {
      $AT = new Fruits;
      $AT->user_id=$user->id;
      $AT->fruit_id=$fruits[$a];
      $AT->save();
    }
}
```

What this is doing is checking if the fruits selections is empty and if it isnt, delete existing fruit associated with the user and create new ones.

is this really ugly because I feel as though it is. I was not to sure how to check if the fruit id already exists for that user and if it doesent create it.
Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
Schema::create('user_fruits', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('fruit_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('fruit_id')->references('id')->on('fruits')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: can you share your table migration user and fruit? you need search user_id in table fruit, and IF it doesnt exist create new ones.

Comment: @Diego182 Hey i have added my user_fruits table.

Comment: Are you using the pivot table method to store `hasMany` relations??

Comment: @BashartheCoder The table i mentioned above is the one storing the many relations, the fruits table which is not there is just to store the fruit ids and names of fruits, the above table is to save the id of the user, the fruit thats all

Comment: I think people are looking to deep into this. All i want to know is of a simple way to refrence my user_fruits table, and see if the $AT->fruit_id=$fruits[$a]; exists with the user id,  Otherwise Ill probably just leave it as is i mean deleting them all and rentering when anyone saves a user profile is probably quite bad though

Comment: I think you should the sync method to update because for many to many relation you need to use sync method.
you can check this tutorial (https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/23)
you can also check 21 and 22 episode. I think it will be helpful to work with many to many relations

Answer (score 0):

A curious omission of Eloquent is `sync()` or even an opposite to `save()` for hasMany relations. So you have to delete and add again. An alternative that doesn't involve expensive multiple deletes and inserts is to check each fruit and delete (and add) only those necessary. I'm monitoring this closely and if there's nothing that comes out of it, I might make a PR to add this to Eloquent.

Here's a slightly cleaner way of doing what you already have:

```
Fruits::where('user_id', $user->id)->delete();

$fruits = [];
foreach ($data['fruits'] as $key => $value) {
    $fruit = new Fruits();
    $fruit->id = $key;
    $fruits[] = $fruit;
}

$user->saveMany($fruits);
```